# How do I remove the last character from a string variable?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get all of Google Play's categories into separate links, for example `https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ART_AND_DESIGN`

This is the code I came up with

```
use LWP::Simple;

$url     = 'https://play.google.com';
my $html = get($url);

while ( $html =~ /href\=\"(\/store\/apps\/category\/)([A-Z]+"|[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+"|[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+")/g ) {

    print "$url$1$2\n";
}
```

The problem is that `$2` also gives me the quotation mark at the end, for example `https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ART_AND_DESIGN"`

How do I get rid of the double quote `"` when printing?

Comment: Remove `([A-Z]+"|[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+"|[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+")` and put `(\w+)"` instead.

Comment: Put the `"` outside of your capturing parenthesis. `...(a"|b"|c")...` becomes `...(a|b|c)"...`. You can also use alternative delimiters for the expression, to get rid of the hard to read `\/` like `m{/a/b/c/...}`.

Comment: You really don't want to use regex to parse HTML. If you want to parse websites, take a look at WWW::Mechanize instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you should really be processing the HTML with an appropriate module, but I'll explain the problems

First, instead of escaping all those slashes you can use a different delimiter for the pattern. `/.../` is the same as `m/.../`, but if you use the `m` (for "match") then you can pick a different delimiter. Here I've used exclamation marks `!`

Secondly, there's little point in adding the closing double quote to the second capture, or to give all the alternatives of zero, one, or two underscores. The `\w` metacharacter matches "word" characters, and is the same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]` i.e. alphanumerics or underscore. You just need to match as many of those as possible

This test should work

```
$html =~  m!href="(/store/apps/category/)(\w+)!g
```

And to answer your original question, the `chop` function removes the last character of a string. It won't work on `$2` because that value is read-only so you would have needed to declare your own variable and copy it first

```
my $capture = $2;
chop $capture;
```